# How to display variables from Laravel controller to view javascript with specific index

Tags: laravel, chart.js, laravel-6, chartjs-2.6.0

I want to pass variable indexes from laravel controller to view on the javascript area so i can create chart

My Controller

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\GenderSeries;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class EventDashboardController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $titles = GenderSeries::select('titles','numbers')->get();
        return view('events.dashboard',compact('titles'));
    }
}
```

and my view file

```
@extends('layouts.templates.event')
@section('title','Store Dashboard')
@section('content')

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <canvas id="genderCount" width="100%" height="80"></canvas>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <canvas id="genderTitle" width="100%" height="80"></canvas>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection

@section('scripts')
    <script>
        //Show graph of individuals count by gender
        var ctx = document.getElementById('genderTitle');
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: {!! $titles !!},
                datasets: [{
                    label: '# Gender Series',
                    data:{!! $titles !!},
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true,
                        }
                    }]
                },
            }
        });
    </script>
@endsection
```

On the javascript labels, I want to display titles on the javascript dataset data I want to display the numbers to make a chart.

when I tried that I got this and view my source code

```
<script>
        //Show graph of individuals count by gender
        var ctx = document.getElementById('genderCount');
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'doughnut',
            data: {
                labels: [{"title":"Feminism","numbers":"50"}],
                datasets: [{
                    label: '# Individual By Gender',
                    data:[{"title":"Feminism","numbers":"50"}],
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true,
                        }
                    }]
                },

            }
        });
</script>
```

I need help to fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the collection method `pluck()`:

```php
@section('scripts')
    <script>
        //Show graph of individuals count by gender
        var ctx = document.getElementById('genderTitle');
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: {!! $titles->pluck('title') !!},
                datasets: [{
                    label: '# Gender Series',
                    data:{!! $titles->pluck('numbers') !!},
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true,
                        }
                    }]
                },
            }
        });
    </script>
@endsection
```

Comment: @AntwenySawe dont forget to set it as the answer to your question (and upvote if it's perfect for you)

Comment: I already did but on up vote I can't because I still have low reputation for my vot be accepted